# 20.04 Samba, Apache2, and Minecraft Server not sharing

Tags: networking, server, apache2, samba, minecraft

I can start, and run all these services, but I can not use them.
I can see the hostname for my Samba Server, but not connect through IP or Hostname. I cannot access the website, or Minecraft Server through the DDNS, nor the IP.

I have all these services allowed through UFW, set Hostname, and checked in Hostnamectl, as well as forwarded through Router security.

Comment: We need more detail about how your network is set up. Are you trying to access your Samba/web/Minecraft server from a different device on the same LAN, or over the Internet? Is the server behind a router/modem/firewall? Can you ping it? Can the server ping the client?

Comment: I am connecting to all through my pain PC, both are through eth cables directly to the router/modem combo. I can ping the server, and the DDNS, but not the hostname. I can connect to the internet on my server, and ping google.

Comment: This question may need to be split up in three separate ones...Is the web server running? Can you do `wget localhost` on the server? (it should get you something like `index.html`.) Do you have `UFW` or `iptables` activated on the server?

Comment: Yes, all services are running-I touched on some of these in the question-I can do "wget localhost", I have my own HTML website, I use UFW, but iptables is installed, however, inactive. I also believe this to be the same problem for all, as to why it is one question, not 3. They are all set up and configured to everything I have read, and used previously and worked, but since building a new server, and upgrading to 20.04 have failed to work properly.